# can http only cookies be accessed by xss via analyzing headers?

Tags: javascript, xss

I was taking a look at http only cookies and i noticed they are transferred via headers when visiting the site (live http headers). Then i thought, how would it be possible via xss to access that data which contains the http only cookies?
Many thanks to whoever can help..

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, if the browser supports the http only cookie, it would not let the XSS to read the cookie if there is HttpOnly header. So it is not the matter of the XSS script but the browser. If you do want to access, you can consider some filtering to get rid of the HttpOnly header in some way.

Comment: there is always a way, the matter is how.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be ways to to do this. One could use java, flash,silverlight or xhr to do this. Most vulnersbilities have been closed. If TRACE requests are enabled on the server, using xss to do an xhr TRACE request may still work though. This is called Cross-Site Tracing: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross_Site_Tracing